# Javascript - Sumar los valores de un input range

Tags: javascript

Quiero saber si existe la forma de sumar los valores de 2 input range e imprimir dicho resultado.

Necesito que el usuario ingrese los dos input y les mande un resultado.

Ya pude hacer que se muestre el valor de solo un input, pero ahora con que sume ambos valores es donde tengo problemas

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("PechoC");
var output = document.getElementById("valor");

output.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML =  this.value + "Gr";
}
```

```html
<input type="range" min="30" max="46" value="0"  id="PechoC">
<input type="range" min="20" max="36" value="0"  id="cuelloC"> 
<p>Valor: <span id="valor"></span></p>
```

Comment: @BetaM Hola, por el valor que ya tienen por defecto

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Básicamente ya casi lo tienes. Debes usar un manejador de evento para cada `slider`, y en el mismo sumar el valor que tiene el `slider` actual más el valor del otro `slider`.

Puedes usar el método [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/parseInt) para convertir los valores de tipo `String` en valores tipo `Number`.

Por ejemplo:

```js
var sliderPechoC = document.getElementById("PechoC");
var sliderCuelloC = document.getElementById("cuelloC");
var output = document.getElementById("valor");

output.innerHTML = parseInt(sliderPechoC.value) + parseInt(sliderCuelloC.value);

sliderPechoC.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML =  parseInt(sliderCuelloC.value) + parseInt(this.value) + "Gr";
}

sliderCuelloC.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML =  parseInt(sliderPechoC.value) + parseInt(this.value) + "Gr";
}
```

```html
<input type="range" min="30" max="46" value="0"  id="PechoC">
<input type="range" min="20" max="36" value="0"  id="cuelloC"> 
<p>Valor: <span id="valor"></span></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

El valor de un input es una cadena de texto. Para sumar el valor de varios sliders hay que transformar el valor en un número.

Por favor lea los comentarios en el código.

```js
//el array de los sliders
var sliders = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("input[type='range']"));

var output = document.getElementById("valor");
//llama la función que suma los sliders
sumar();


//para cada slider del array de los sliders
sliders.forEach(s=>{
//al cambiar el valor (on input)
s.addEventListener("input",(e)=>{
   //llama la función que suma los sliders
   sumar();  
})
})
  
function sumar(){
let val = 0;//inicia el valor val
   sliders.forEach(_s=>{
   //para cada slider suma el valor de este a la variable val
      val += Number(_s.value);
   })
   
   output.innerHTML =  val + "Gr"; 
}
```

```html
<input type="range" min="30" max="46" value="30"  id="PechoC">
<input type="range" min="20" max="36" value="20"  id="cuelloC"> 
<p>Valor: <span id="valor"></span></p>
```

Comment: Excelente, me gusta tu aproximación y la forma en que separas las responsabilidades. +1.